# MySQL: Show Unique key definition by name

Tags: mysql, schema

I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 1901: Duplicate entry '3-3820-50-0' for key
 'UNQ_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_DTIME_ENTT_TYPE_ID_ENTT_ID_ATTR_ID_STORE_ID'
```

How can I find out which table and columns this is referring to?

Comment: What version of MySQL? Are you using innodb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
select table_schema, table_name, column_name
from information_schema.key_column_usage
where constraint_name = 'UNQ_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_DTIME_ENTT_TYPE_ID_ENTT_ID_ATTR_ID_STORE_ID'
order by ordinal_position
```

Comment: Yes it would, +1 !!! Hope you don't mind but I added `table_schema` so that the database of the table is known as well.